# Not Show The Images In viewPager in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I want to show a set of images inside of recycle View Cell. In ViewHolder I have created the instant of ViewPager. And in onBindViewHolder I set the adapter of ViewPager. But Images are not shown. Please some one suggest some solution so that I can overcome this problem. I am sending my code.

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<AndroidVersion> android_versions;
private Context context;

public DataAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<AndroidVersion> android_versions) {
    this.context = context;
    this.android_versions = android_versions;

}

@Override
public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    viewHolder.tv_android.setText(android_versions.get(i).getAndroid_version_name());
    viewHolder.img_android.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
    int images[] = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4};
    MyCustomPagerAdapter myCustomPagerAdapter = new MyCustomPagerAdapter(this.context, images);
    viewHolder.viewPager.setAdapter(myCustomPagerAdapter);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return android_versions.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView tv_android;
    ImageView img_android;
    ViewPager viewPager;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        tv_android = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_android);
        img_android = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img_android);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    }
}
```

}

====== MainActivity inside onCreate===========

```
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    ArrayList androidVersions = prepareData();
    DataAdapter adapter = new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext(),androidVersions);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

---

```
    private ArrayList prepareData(){

    ArrayList android_version = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<android_version_names.length;i++){
        AndroidVersion androidVersion = new AndroidVersion();
        androidVersion.setAndroid_version_name(android_version_names[i]);
        androidVersion.setAndroid_image_url(android_image_urls[i]);
        android_version.add(androidVersion);
    }
    return android_version;
}
```

Comment: i think you add fragment into viewpager and fragment handle recyclerview data. not directly add adapter into view pager.

Comment: I am thankful to you if you sent me tutorial or some source code.

Comment: ok i provide my code for viewpager and recycler view.

Comment: Please sent it so that I  can implement it in my project .

Comment: Please sent it I am waiting your reply

Comment: i am provide some code but not provide xml code i hope you can mange.

Comment: sir still not understand about your code. I am thankful to you if you send me a sample project.

Answer (score 0):

this code you can change according your needs i provide code follow step by step ..
make adapter to add fragment into viewpager..

```
 public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        mFragmentList = null;
        mFragmentTitleList = null;
        container.removeAllViews();
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }
}

public void opendSearchFriendFragment() {
    FragmentController.addSearchFriendFragment(getActivity());
}
```

}

then after make fragment to show viewpager and add fragment into adapter then after add adapter into viewpager..

```
public class FollowersFragment extends Fragment {


private TabLayout mTbFollowers;
private ViewPager mVPFollowers;
private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;


public static FollowersFragment newInstance() {
    return new FollowersFragment();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.followers_fragment, container, false);
    initViews(root);
    return root;
}



private void initViews(View root) {
    mTbFollowers = (TabLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.ffTbFollower);
    mVPFollowers = (ViewPager) root.findViewById(R.id.ffVpFollowers);
    setupViewPager(mVPFollowers);
    mTbFollowers.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mTbFollowers.setupWithViewPager(mVPFollowers);
        }
    });

    mTbFollowers.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab p_tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab p_tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab p_tab) {

        }
    });

    mVPFollowers.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mTbFollowers));

    mVPFollowers.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Fragment mFragment = adapter.getItem(position);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

}


private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(FollowerListFragment.newInstance(Constants.FOLLOWERS), Constants.FOLLOWERS);
    adapter.addFragment(FollowerListFragment.newInstance(Constants.FOLLOWING), Constants.FOLLOWING);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);

}
```

}

then after make recycler view adapter like below ..

```
public class FollowersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FollowersAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {

private List<UserData> mFollowersList = new ArrayList<UserData>();

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private String mSelectedTab;

public FollowersAdapter(Context context, List<UserData> mFollowersList, String mSelectedTab) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mFollowersList = mFollowersList;
    this.mSelectedTab = mSelectedTab;
    this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public interface OnRecyclerItemClickListener {

    void onViewItemClicked(UserData userData);

}

OnRecyclerItemClickListener onRecyclerItemClickListener;

public void setOnRecyclerItemListener(OnRecyclerItemClickListener _onRecyclerItemClickListener) {
    this.onRecyclerItemClickListener = _onRecyclerItemClickListener;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != mFollowersList ? mFollowersList.size() : 0);
}

@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.follower_row_layout, parent, false);
    return new ItemViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final UserData userData = mFollowersList.get(position);

    if (mSelectedTab.equals(Constants.FOLLOWERS) && userData.isFollower()) {
        holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if (mSelectedTab.equals(Constants.FOLLOWING) && !userData.isFollower()) {
        holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    holder.mTvFollowerName.setText(userData.getUserName());

    Glide.with(context)
            .load(userData.getProfilePicPath())
            .dontAnimate()
            .placeholder(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.placeholder01))
            .error(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.placeholder01))
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(holder.mIvFollowerImage);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (onRecyclerItemClickListener != null)
                onRecyclerItemClickListener.onViewItemClicked(userData);
        }
    });

}

class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ImageView mIvFollowerImage;
    private TextView mTvFollowerName;

    public ItemViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        mTvFollowerName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.frlTvFollowerName);
        mIvFollowerImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.frlIvFollowersImage);
    }
}
```

}

then after implement this adapter into fragment class that add into view pager like below ..
define recycler view and other things into fragment then make some changes into below adapter method.

```
 private void setAdapter(ArrayList<UserData> userDataArrayList) {
    if (followersAdapter == null) {
        if (!userDataArrayList.isEmpty()) {
            mTvEmpty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            followersAdapter = new FollowersAdapter(getActivity(), userDataArrayList, mSelectedTab);
            mRvFollowers.setAdapter(followersAdapter);

            followersAdapter.setOnRecyclerItemListener(new FollowersAdapter.OnRecyclerItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onViewItemClicked(UserData userData) {
                    FragmentController.addOtherUserProfileFragment(getActivity(), mUserId, "" + userData.getUserID());
                }
            });

        } else {
            mTvEmpty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    } else {
        followersAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, userDataArrayList.size());
    }
}
```